# Возможность перевести GC в режим реального времени

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора, производительность

Недавно увидел что на хабре [промелькнула](http://habrahabr.ru/post/198238/#comment_6961622) информация о том, что

> ..в C# есть возможность перевести GC в
> режим реального времени (возможность
> гарантировать выполнение кода
> последовательно без перерыва на сборку
> мусора).

может поподробней кто нибудь пожалуйста объяснить как это сделать?

Comment: Звучит довольно странно. Есть фоновая сборка, есть приоритеты сборки. И всегда нужно исходить из задачи, может это можно решить другим путем? Может имелось ввиду установка приоритета потока GC в realtime? Но это никак не гарантирует "возможность гарантировать выполнение кода последовательно без перерыва на сборку мусора"

Comment: Извините ради бога, а _зачем вам_? Если производительность настолько критична, почему вы пишете не на C или там на ассемблере?

Comment: @VladD это же очевидно зачем. Чего же вы не предложили сразу в машинном коде писать, ведь это так *удобно*

Comment: @wefwefgwe: просто для нормальных случаев производительности GC с головой хватает. У вас и правда GC настолько тормозит систему, что это заметно? Или у вас realtime-приложение?

Для realtime и правда лучше писать на C, и поменьше пользоваться библиотечными функциями (malloc там какой-нибудь).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В пространстве имен System.Runtime имеется статический класс GCSettings, у которого есть свойство LatencyMode, определяющее уровень вмешательства сборщика в работу вашего приложения при выполнении сборки мусора. Подробнее о режимах, регулируемых этим свойством, можно прочитать [в этой статье](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx)